# How to get list of empty parcels (without building)

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I have 2 table: 1. parcel 2. building

How to get list of empty parcels (without building)?

I can get parcel with building by use: `ST_DWithin(parcel.geom, building.geom, 0)`

...so i made my own solution - i call this sql after insert new parcels

```
--sql start
--first set all free to 1

update parcel  set free=1;

--then set free to 0 for parcel with building 

update parcel  set free=0 where id in (    
  select distinct on(p.id) p.id  
  from   parcel as p,   building as b  
  where  ST_DWithin(p.geom, b.geom, 0)  );

-- so next i can call 

select * from parcel where free=0;

-- it is super fast ;)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cleanest way is with a left join where you aggregate on the buildings and then select parcels that have less then 1 building.
You have to decide yourself whether ST_Intersects or ST_Contains fits your case better. ST_DWithin is not a suitable selector here, it will only make your query slower.

```
SELECT parcel.id,parcel.geom
FROM parcel
LEFT JOIN building ON ST_Intersects(parcel.geom, building.geom)
WHERE count(building.geom) < 1
GROUP BY parcel.id, parcel.geom
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your parcel table has id field.

```
select * --select parcels that are not in parcels containing builging
from parcel 
where id not in ( select id 
                  from parcel,building 
                  where ST_Contains(parcel.geom,building.geom) --select parcels that contain building
                )
```